# Why Auto-Completion doesn't work in newly created protocol header file in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autocomplete, protocols

I just create a protocol header file by doing:

File -> New -> File -> (Cocoa Touch) Objective-C Protocol -> Next -> input protocol name -> Next -> choose my Target -> Create

when I trying to create a method list in the protocol header file. I noticed Dynamic Typing doesn't work. When I type "NSStr" in other files, usually a Class list will automatically popup and all classes are marked with colors. why it doesn't work in protocol header file?

BTW, I tried putting protocol code in existing class file, that works. why it doesn't work in separated file?

Some key words will work, such as "void". the popup list will show. but other key words like "NSString" will not be recognized.

My protocol is like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol PanToSwitchViewDelegateProtocol <NSObject>

@end
```

Comment: Did I miss anything? Anything wrong with Naming?

Comment: Guess what? All of a sudden! It's working without doing anything!!!! I think it's a Xcode BUG!!! :(

Comment: It's a Bug!! Tried many times! Xcode 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Comment: I bet you added your protocol to your project in the meanwhile (meaning your protocol is now part of your target). Code completion in Xcode is syntax aware. A non-linked header is not part of a target and thus the code completion will not work as expected on this file. You may call it a bug, I would call it an unfulfilled expectation.

Comment: @auco is correct. When you create a new protocol is not added to your target since it is a header file. Because of this you don't get the benefits of dynamic typing. Easy solution is to add it to your project/target when you create it by clicking the checkbox at the bottom.

Comment: I was wrong about the BUG thing, It's not a bug. After importing the protocol header file in any .m files, Auto-Completion will start working.

Comment: @auco in fact, I did try add to target. It doesn't matter whether clicking the checkbox or not. :) Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @jazou: only implementation (.m) files can be added to the target by clicking the checkbox of Xcode's GUI. So the protocol must either be defined in a .m file which you can add as target (by clicking the checkbox) or you need to #import the interface (.h) with your protocol to an already included .m file. In any case, there must be a .m file with that protocol present (or #imported) in a project target in order for Xcode's autocompletion to work as expected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just experimented and I see exactly the same thing.  I think the problem is that the compiler will not scan the file unless it is imported into a file that is scanned.

If you import your protocol header into a `.m` file and compile it for luck, you should start getting the autocomplete on NSString.

**EDIT**

It's clear from the comments on my answer and elsewhere that jazou2012 is under a misapprehension.

Autocomplete has nothing to say about whether a module is correct or not.  Autocomplete may fail to find an identifier for several reasons, even if that identifier has been correctly defined. For instance, I was able to replicate Jazou's problem with NSString in a protocol even though `Foundation.h` was imported.

However, as soon as I imported my protocol header into `.m` file, the autocomplete started recognising `NSString`.  My guess is that autocomplete only starts indexing files if they are visible to the compiler.

If you want to catch compilation errors, you need to compile the code.  If the compiler says "no errors or warnings", your code is OK regardless of what autocomplete says.

Comment: I think it will work! but to have a clearer view, I really hope the to have a separated protocol file. Does it mean Xcode just doesn't support it??? But why provide an option of letting people create protocol header files?

Comment: @jazou2012 Yes you can have a separate protocol file.  Just make sure it is imported somewhere in a .m if you want autocomplete to work properly.

Comment: Importing the protocol to .m in other Classes cannot make Keywords be recognized in Protocol file.

Comment: @jazou2012 it worked for me when I tried it (you may need to run the compiler - or at least save the protocol file).

Comment: Yes, JeremyP is right!!!! When I imported the protocol header file in a .m file. and CMD + B. everything works fine than. Thank you very much.!!!

Comment: It might still be considered a bug, albeit a minor one.  You should probably report it to Apple.

Comment: Yeah, probably~ I think it worth a bug report~

Comment: Just fired a bug report to Apple ~~~=>

Comment: Worked for me by importing into a .h file

Comment: Didn't work for me by importing in imported .h file. had to import in a .m as well.

Answer (score 1):

Either import into the class header or the implementation file or in another place where it will be visible, like another header of imports or the precompiled header. 
The protocols in Foundation are visible always because they're imported with Foundation. 
Cocoa includes Foundation so view classes will include Cocoa protocols. 
Core Animation and WebKit is not included by default so you need to import those to see any protocols they include.

Comment: The default setting already has "#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>" and classes such as NSString and NSArray are belong to Foundation. But when I type "NSString", it will not be recognized. Why?

Comment: Do you mean that, It just won't work in a separated protocol file?

Comment: If you create a new protocol, you need to import it somewhere visible to the files that need to know about it.